# email regular expression does not validate the part after period

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am trying to validate email address in my html page using angular directive.

To me valid email address is

hello@mycompany.com

The following regular expression allows following email address

hello@mycompany

What kind of regular expression I could use that would also enforce the ".com" part of email address meaning enforce "." and any thing after "."

I have researched internet and used different listed regular expression but none are working

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': registerUpdateForm.Email.$invalid }">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input required type="email" data-ng-model="auth.Email"
               data-ng-pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$"
               id="email" name="Email" class="form-control" />  <!--ng-pattern="matchPattern"/>-->
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value is a `Regexp` or an inline pattern, which in javascript looks like `/pattern/`. The regular expression itself looks good, so just try adding the forward slashes at the beginning and end:

```
<input required type="email" data-ng-model="auth.Email"
               data-ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"
               id="email" name="Email" class="form-control" />
```

[Plunker Demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIwtFpwK3U3e1K0yuWZX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) for `<input type="email">` says that the email address must match the regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

so that would be a reasonable start on something like (untested)

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.com$/
```

Note that you can't restrict the top-level domain to {2,4} characters any more, if you want to allow more than just ".com": [Proposed domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Proposed_domains).